# How to write services with CPython?

Tags: python, soap, service, soa, cpython

Does CPython have any library that helps to write binding-independent services?

I have found some SOAP libraries for Python, but it misses the flexibility of choosing the binding at runtime.

Comment: Do you want to register and unregister functions remotely, dynamically and seamlessly?

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer that's not necessary. Anything similar to WCF would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages such as [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html?highlight=xml%20rpc%20servers#module-SimpleXMLRPCServer) (part of the Python standard library), [SimpleJSONRPCServer](http://www.freenet.org.nz/dojo/pyjson/), and probably at least some of the SOAP server-side libraries you found (the good ones;-), are based on the concept of *registering* functions and instances with the package to make them available to clients of the service -- basically you write your service's functionality independently, just exposing that functionality as functions and classes (much as you would for any other application's core logic, not just a service), and then, at runtime (presumably, mostly at server startup time), you register those functions, and instances of those classes, so they become accessible as "the service".  I'd call that pretty much a "binding-independent" approach;-).